# For/ while loops until sequence is maintained

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, break

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
input <- structure(list(rank = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L), sequence = c("HRIGRGGRYGRKGVAI", 
"TQIDELPVDFAAYLGE", "AFSIGLLQRLDFRHNL", "QNDKIAPQDQDSFLDD", "SMHAEMPKSDRERVMN", 
"AQSVIFANTRRKVDWI", "PGRVSDVIKRGALRTE", "AEVISRIGEFLSNSSK", "GGDIIAQAQSGTGKTG", 
"TFVGGTRVQDDLRKLQ", "QGLVLSPTRELALQTA", "DWIAEKLNQSNHTVSS", "NIVINFDLPTNKENYL", 
"AGVIVAVGTPGRVSDV", "SDRERVMNTFRSGSSR", "GFEKPSSIQQRAIAPF", "SGTGKTGAFSIGLLQR", 
"LDTLMDLYETVSIAQS", "VRPIPSFDDMPLHQNL", "MPEEVLELTKKFMRDP", "QQRAIAPFTRGGDIIA", 
"LHEIEAHYHTQIDELP", "LVARGIDVHHVNIVIN", "ANTRRKVDWIAEKLNQ", "VLVLDEADEMLSQGFA", 
"RGALRTESLRVLVLDE", "PQDQDSFLDDQPGVRP", "YGRKGVAINFVTEKDV", "SSKFCETFVGGTRVQD", 
"RVLVTTDLVARGIDVH"), start_position = c(353L, 388L, 79L, 3L, 
296L, 268L, 155L, 111L, 63L, 130L, 96L, 281L, 337L, 146L, 304L, 
45L, 72L, 255L, 22L, 212L, 53L, 379L, 326L, 274L, 174L, 164L, 
9L, 361L, 124L, 319L), score = c(0.92, 0.89, 0.87, 0.87, 0.86, 
0.86, 0.85, 0.85, 0.84, 0.84, 0.79, 0.79, 0.78, 0.78, 0.77, 0.76, 
0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.74, 0.74, 0.73, 0.72, 0.72, 0.71, 0.68, 
0.67, 0.65, 0.63)), .Names = c("rank", "sequence", "start_position", 
"score"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

What I want to do is the following. Looking at `input$rank`, I want to add up the scores under `input$score` until the sequence under `input$rank` is held.

As an example, considering the first sequence, which goes from **rows** 1:36 (the 37th value under `input$rank`is a 1 - note that there are repeated values under `input$rank`), I would have a sum of 26.76 - I obtained this by doing `sum(input$score[1:36])`.

I thought about inserting `break` or `next` within a `for`or `while` loop, although I am not that familiar with those arguments within a loop.

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: It can be a vector or another column, it does not matter much as long as the order is kept. I will then bind the output to another data frame

Comment: What do you mean by "until the sequence under input$rank is held"? Also notice that in the example data you posted there are only 30 rows.

Comment: yes, I've just pasted part of my data frame, as it has over 4k rows. Sequence held I mean that the sequence is not broken i.e. is continuous. In my example, the sequence goes uninterruptedly from 1:23, then the next number under rank is 1, which means the sequence was interrupted.

Comment: Right, I realize you can't paste the whole 4k rows, what I'm trying to imply is that the data you've posted doesn't let us reproduce the output you're asking for, because it's only 30 rows long (not 36). It's no wonder Federico couldn't figure it out. It would be helpful if you could rework your example data to have it reflect the features you have in your actual data. You could just make up a rank, say `1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4` or something, to use as the basis of a simpler and more concise true [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is closer to what you're looking for.
What I did was test a differenced version of the rank vector for values less than zero and do a cumulative sum on that. The result is then used as the grouping vector in a call to `aggregate()`.

```
set.seed(1)
rank <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5)
score <- round(runif(length(rank)), 2)
input <- data.frame(rank, score)
input <- cbind(group=cumsum(c(-1, diff(input$rank)) < 0), input)
input
#    group rank score
# 1      1    1  0.27
# 2      1    2  0.37
# 3      1    3  0.57
# 4      1    5  0.91
# 5      1    5  0.20
# 6      2    1  0.90
# 7      2    2  0.94
# 8      2    2  0.66
# 9      2    3  0.63
# 10     3    1  0.06
# 11     3    2  0.21
# 12     3    4  0.18
# 13     3    4  0.69
# 14     3    5  0.38

aggregate(score ~ group, data=input, sum)
#   group score
# 1     1  2.32
# 2     2  3.13
# 3     3  1.52
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(input[c(1,4)],by=list(input$rank),sum)
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: not really, unfortunately. From my edited answer, you can see that, considering the first sequence, I'll have 26.76 as output and this value is not present if I use your code. In addition to that, I have 65 sequences in total and the output using your code gives me 47 sequences.